# Why does redis 3.2 refuse to create a background fsync?

Tags: redis, fsync

Here is the code snippet in the end of `flushAppendOnlyFile` function in aof.c, which writes aof buffer on disk.

```
/* Perform the fsync if needed. */
if (server.aof_fsync == AOF_FSYNC_ALWAYS) {
    server.aof_last_fsync = server.unixtime;
} else if ((server.aof_fsync == AOF_FSYNC_EVERYSEC &&
            server.unixtime > server.aof_last_fsync)) {
    // Why create fsync job only while sync_in_progress is false?
    if (!sync_in_progress) aof_background_fsync(server.aof_fd);
    server.aof_last_fsync = server.unixtime;
}
```

Redis bio implements a background job list for fsync. Function `aof_background_fsync` appends a new fsync job to list.

Why dose redis create fsync job on this file only while `sync_in_progress` is false? If `sync_in_progress` is true, there is several fsync jobs waiting to be executed. Why does redis refuse to append this fsync job in such condition?

(Here is whole [flushAppendOnlyFile function](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3.2/src/aof.c#L287))